# Using for loops to traverse through an array in shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

following is my test code to traverse though elements placed in an array. However I am getting the specified error. Please help me understand what the error is, and why I am getting it, so that I can rectify my mistake.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
categories=("men" "women" "kids")

for i in "${categories[@]}"
   do:
       echo $i;

   done
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the colon exists after `do`

```
$ categories=("men" "women" "kids")
$ for i in "${categories[@]}";do echo $i;done
men
women
kids
```